# Find the base number $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems

The unit digits of each of $X$ and $Y$ when expressed to the base $n$ is $a$. If the unit digit of $\frac{X+Y}{2}$ when expressed in base $n$ is either $2$ or $5$, find $n$
This was an MCQ type question.

The options given were:- 8,6,10,12 and 14.

I tried a lot but could not figure out how to start the problem. I'm only looking for a useful hint, not the full solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

P.S:- I understand that this is a very ill-formatted question and also my saying that "i could not figure out" would inspire some suspicion on the reader's part...but I assure you that this I have genuinely tried to solve this question. Also, this is not a homework problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that all of the possible bases are even numbers. We will need that.

Let's look at what happens in base $10$.

\begin{array}{c|c}
a \mod{10} & 2a \mod{10} \\
\hline
0, 5 & 0 \\
1, 6 & 2 \\
2, 7 & 4 \\
3, 8 & 6 \\
4, 9 & 8 \\
\hline
\end{array}

There are exactly two values of $a$ for each value of $2a$. That this is true for every even base, $B$, follows from

$$2a \equiv 2b \mod{B} \iff a \equiv b \mod \frac B2$$

Since the possible values of $a$ are $2$ and $5$. Then $\frac B2 = 5 - 2 = 3$ and so $B = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint. If we work in the familiar base $10$ and have $a=1$ here are two examples:

$$X=11, Y=91, \frac {X+Y}2=51$$

$$X=11, Y=81, \frac {X+Y}2=46$$

Does that help you to see what might going on here?

Comment: No.
 Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @SauravvvMishra You wanted a hint, so I gave you one. I deliberately wanted to give you something to think about. Can you see how different final digits arise? Are other final digits possible withy $a=1$ in base $10$? I think you need to work with a few concrete examples (make some up, and try different bases) so that your solution is based on your own understanding and not mine.

Comment: ,if I let a=2 and n=6, then $\frac{x+y}{2}$ would satisfy the given condition. Also, I think the point you are trying to make is that for any pair of $a$ and $n$, there are only two possible unit digits of $\frac{x+y}{2}$ in the base $n$

Comment: @SauravvvMishra You are on the right lines, and obviously with a choice of answers, spotting one gets you there. Can you see why all the suggested bases are even? Is there anything more you can say about the two possibilities for even bases? Can spot and prove a pattern?